# How to filter only subscriptions in a particular state using Azure API Management API (Get error: Filtering is not supported for property 'state')

Tags: http, azure-api-management, apim

Is it possible to get a list of only the subscriptions in a particular state e.g. tried this but it doesn't work:

`https://*servicename*.management.azure-api.net/subscriptions/*serviceGUID*/resourceGroups/*resourceGroup*/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/*servicename*/users/1/subscriptions?$filter=properties/state%20eq%20'submitted'&api-version=2022-08-01`

But this returns:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ValidationError",
        "message": "Filtering is not supported for property 'state'.",
        "details": null
    }
}
```

Obviously this would look like filtering isn't available on this property - but surely there must be a way of filtering it? Would've thought filtering out those in a particular state would be a desired feature. Am I just using the wrong approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the below URL to filter the subscriptions in a particular `state`.

***URL***-

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/{serviceName}/subscriptions?api-version=2022-08-01
```

I am sending the request as shown below and getting the expected output for the same.

[image]

In your case, you are using ***users/1*** in the URL. Please correct your URL as per [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/subscription/list?view=rest-apimanagement-2022-08-01&tabs=HTTP), you will get the expected output too.

Comment: That's fine but I want to get all the subscriptions for a particular user, will that not return all subscriptions, for all users?

Comment: @Blingers You can use `properties/state%20eq%20'cancelled' and properties/ownerId%20eq%20'1'` filter for particular user